# Android: how to use a single HTTP/2 connection?

Tags: android, networking, https, httpurlconnection, http2

Our mobile apps need to make **2 different HTTPS requests at the same time**. We would like to make sure that only 1 connection is used. Our server supports **HTTP/2**.

On **iOS**, everything works well: only 1 connection is established.

On **Android**, our app is establishing 2 different connections.

Is it possible to achieve the same also on Android?

**UPDATE:**

I found out the reason: Android's recommended http client `HttpUrlConnection` doesn't support HTTP/2!

What recommendation do you have for using HTTP/2 on Android?

Comment: You can try to use `System.setProperty("http.keepAlive","true");` You will need to maintain the connection and take care of `urlConnection.disconnect();` yourself. -- I removed my answer in order to add this comment (it will get more attention- people usually look for unanswered questions) because I am a bit uncertain about the results of this suggestion. I simply read the docs -- I have never had any issues with connections or connection pools in the past... so I really haven't dug too deep.

Comment: @Barns It looks like HttpUrlConnection uses HTTP/1.1 and not HTTP/2. That might well be the reason!

Comment: According to the docs `OkHttp`  supports HTTP/2.

Comment: but it looks like on HttpUrlConnection, it is forced to use HTTP/1.1: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44122781/okhttp-not-selecting-http2-on-android-7-0

Comment: I am certain you are correct about HttpUrlConnection, I am referring to `OKHttp` :: https://github.com/square/okhttp

Comment: so, should an external library be used for HTTP/2 on Android? is there any specific reason why HTTP/2 is not officially supported?

Comment: I'm not really sure. I use HttpUrlConnection in all my apps. But, I know many who are really happy with `OKHttp` It even supports async requests without needing to wrap in a `AsyncTask`

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I was able to make HTTP/2 requests on Android, by using the **OkHttp** library:

http://square.github.io/okhttp/

It's very disappointing that `HttpUrlConnection` (Android library's default http client) does not support HTTP/2, not even on the latest Android 9!

HTTP/2 support in iOS started on iOS 9, which means 2015, 3 years ago!